# TCL: can foreach be used with regexp?

Tags: tcl

I have txt like:

```
ITEM=a1
*TYPE
ITEM=a2
*TYPE
```

---

I want it to be:

```
ITEM=a1
*TYPE, ADD=a1
ITEM=a2
*TYPE, ADD=a2
```

---

(I am very new to the tcl, and new to here.)
First, I tried:

```
regexp -line {ITEM=(.\*)\\n\\\*TYPE=(.*)} $txt match a b
append b ",ADD=$a"
puts $b
```

---

It works. Then I tried to add foreach:

```
foreach data $txt{
if {[regexp -line {ITEM=(.\*)\\n\\\*TYPE=(.*)} $txt match a b]}{
puts $b
```

---

But it didn't work. it said can't find var `$b`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things going wrong here:

1. Use `regsub`, not `regexp`. `regexp` only matches based on a regular expression whilst `regsub` can perform substitution.
2. You're quoting is incorrect. Quoting is key in Tcl and you should go back and understand the differences between quoting with braces vs quotation marks. In short, with braces, nothing is substituted in execution so no need to escape the `\`. You do need to escape the `*` for the regular expression though.
3. The regular expression also has a few issues such as capitals, you've escaped the first `*` etc but I'll keep this to Tcl.

So, without the `foreach` loop which is not required, the command is re-written as:

```
regsub -all -line {Item=(.*)\n\*TYPE} $txt {\0, ADD=\1} $var
```

This will store the substituted `$txt` variable in the new variable `$var`:

```
Item=a1
*TYPE, ADD=a1
Item=a2
*TYPE, ADD=a2
```

`regsub` stores matches in \1, \2, \3 etc. \0 is the special case for the original match.

See more info here on the [tclers wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/regsub)